# Reading a text from a file that contains \", but it keeps it as \\\" in code

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I have a text file that contains data that looks like this:

`{\"_clientId\":\"123\",\"_timestamp\":22548}`
`{\"_clientId\":\"222\",\"_timestamp\":22590}`

(they have escape characters already)

When I read the file using 
`string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"datafile.txt");` for example, it stores the strings in `lines` as:

`"{\\\"_clientId\\\":\\\"123\\\",\\\"_timestamp\\\":22548}"`
`"{\\\"_clientId\":\\\"222\\\",\\\"_timestamp\\\":22590}"`

My question is:  Is there a way to store them in the string variable without the additional escape characters (store them as they appeared in the file)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines should be stored in your `string[]` exactly as they are entered in the file.

If you look at the lines in your *debugger*, the *debugger* will show the escapes for visualization purposes only.  That is probably what you are seeing.

Edit:

After looking at your example in detail, the problem is that you have already escaped the quotes in your data file.  The data file itself does not contain valid Json.

This should fix the problem:

```
string fixedLine = line.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Then deserialize `fixedLine`.

Comment: The Thing that is I am using Json Deserializer

 `T msg = JsonReader.Deserialize<T>(line);`

So, when it receives a string with double escape characters, the program fails and I get exceptions.

Thanks again,

Comment: @Has: I seriously doubt that `ReadAllLines` is escaping characters.  Can you post a short but complete example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: sure:

`string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"datafile.txt");`
`foreach (string line in lines){`
`MessageCharacterController msg = JsonReader.Deserialize<MessageCharacterController>(line);`
`}`

here, line will contain the double escape characters I mentioned before, and I will get the `Illegal JSON sequence.` exception.

Comment: Which Json deserializer are you using?  Doesn't look like Json.Net.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to deserialize the file using some Deserializer. There are many available, you can use `JSON.NET` or `Servicestack.Text.` Servicestack's serializer and deserializer are the **fastest on the planet**. Using one of these , you can get your `JSON` data without escape characters and can store it or pass to the methods.